# Putting data from a variable into <li> using data separated by space

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to load data from a  variable that contains information and then place them into a string to use on web page using only the space as a divider. I know I have to loop through but I cannot. Shall I perform this in PHP before or use JS to do this? Also is it possible to load up to say 3 at a time? Is it possible to do this? The string looks like this :-

```
$areas = "London Birmingham Leeds Glasgow Bradford Liverpool Edinburgh etc etc"
```

and this is how I would like to place the data :-

```
<h3 class="areas">London</h3>
<h3 class="areas">Birmingham</h3>
<h3 class="areas">Leeds</h3>
```

or something like :-

```
<h3 class="areas">London Birmingham, Leeds</h3>
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Use explode to separate the data. http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php

Comment: use explode function `print_r (explode(" ",$areas ))`, and also i recommend you to first google your quires

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting up a string in PHP with every blank space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020202/splitting-up-a-string-in-php-with-every-blank-space)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need any JS to do that, only the [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) built-in function :

```
$areas_list = explode(' ', $areas);

foreach ($areas_list as $area) {
    echo '<h3 class="areas">' . $area . '</h3>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.explode.php) your `String` into an `Array` and loop through it :

```
$areas = "London Birmingham Leeds Glasgow Bradford Liverpool Edinburgh etc etc";

foreach(explode(' ',$areas) as $area){
  echo '<h3 class="areas">'.$area.'</h3>';
}
```