# How to split an array element with multiple values to get only one of them in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i m storing data from excel into database and

```
$rowDataA = $sheet->rangeToArray('L' . $row . ':'. 'M' . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
echo $rowDataA[0][0];
```

this each cell has two values like "23 43.12" and i want to store only the second value of each cell.

I tried using explode to separate it but its not getting separated from one of the previous queries EXPLODE([Splitting up a string in PHP with every blank space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020202/splitting-up-a-string-in-php-with-every-blank-space))

```
$value1 = explode(" ", $rowDataA[0][0]);
    echo $value1[0]; // piece1
    echo $value1[1];
```

from value1[0] m getting 23 43.12 and from value1[1] m getting undefined offset 1

Comment: What's the value of `$rowDataA[0][0]`?

Comment: 23 43.12 this is the value

Comment: cannot [reproduce](https://3v4l.org/UUR5K)

Comment: its working over there i tried changing the value its still working over there but not on my website. I printed the array $rowDataA ` Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 23 3.74 [1] => 721 457.27 ) ) ` this was the output. can you spot any error here?

Comment: print `$value1` after explode. you may also want to use `var_dump()` instead of `print_r()` to inspect data types too.

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "23 3.74" } this is the output of variable dump. @MarcinOrlowski

Comment: there is one thing i checked is if m replacing space with . its wroking .. so what m understanding by it is that that is not a normal space .. can you guys help me out what it can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that space is creating issue just replace it with some other character or the normal space itself and then use explode

```
 $rowDataA = $sheet->rangeToArray('L' . $row . ':'. 'M' . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
    $str1 = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $rowDataA[0][0]);
    $value1 = explode(' ', $str1);
    echo $value1[1];
```