# How can I extract variables from a string from POST?

Tags: php, parsing, post, foreach

first time here with question but Im stuck and can't figure this out.  Any help is appreciated.

I am sending a string that is delimited with "###" as a "payload".  I want to parse the string to array to get individual strings of data.  I then want to loop through the individual string to extract the variables so I can input in my database.  Im not sure the best way to go about it, I've been testing different methods and either get and empty string response or status 500 code.

Here is example "payload" string I send from POST:

```
key=03968db0386af63d57f48e8cbfd16971&name=LE%252520Tropical%252520Tuffet%252520%25252D%252520Luau&type=Pot%2520with%2520Plant###key=239fa7207c241d8a55743d9988839055&name=Modern%252520Oasis%252520Philodendron%252520Pot%252520%25252D%252520Pink%252520Swirls&type=Pot%2520with%2520Plant
```

```
<?php
$payload = $_POST['payload'];
$records = implode("\n", $payload);
foreach($records as $record){
    list($key,$name,$type) = explode("###", $record);
    echo $key;
}
?>
```

I'm expecting to receive payload from POST, parse to individual strings for each record using the "###" delimiter, extract the key, name, and type from the individual strings so I can add to my data base with mysqli.  So each entry in the database will have a key identifier as primary and the stats of each key.

Thank You

Comment: `implode()` creates a string, not an array. You can't use `foreach` over a string. Did you mean to use `explode()`?

Comment: Your payload string only has one `###`. So you can't assign the result of `explode()` to 3 variables.

Comment: What do you expect the key, name, and type to be?

Comment: variables to add into my database like: INSERT INTO `$db_name`.`$db_table` (
                        `key`,
                        `name`,
                        `type`,

Comment: I meant what should the values of those variables be from that string? To get 3 values, you need two `###` delimiters.

Comment: each string has key=, name=, type= so Im hoping to assign what comes after "=" to the corresponding variable to insert into database. So those would be my 3 variables.  Each ### separates a new item with new set of key, type, name variables.

Comment: I think your right about the implode vs explode, that is likely what I need to do first like $records = explode("###", $payload); Then use that array to loop through each item and in the loop extract each variable $key, $name, $type.  Then insert those variables to my database

Comment: This question is an XY Problem (you should find a better way to construct and port the `$_POST` data than to hack it into multiple segments with a delimiter.  Then the `implode()` step is an unnecessary obstacle -- which error reporting would tell you. Then you already know how to [`explode()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5020202/2943403) and loop. And finally there are plenty of pages on Stack Overflow that demonstrate how to parse a querystring, such as: [Parse query string into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5397726/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should be using `###` to create an array of query strings. Then you can use [`parse_str()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to parse each of the `name=value` parameters into variables.

```
$payload = $_POST['payload'];
$records = explode('###', $payload);
foreach ($records as $record) {
    parse_str($record, $vars);
    ['key' => $key, 'name' => $name, 'type' => $type] = $vars;
    echo $key;
}
```